# Foolproof detection of OutOfmemory in Java

Tags: java

TL;DR: Is there a foolproof (!) way I can detect from my master JVM that my slave JVM spawned via 2 intermediate scripts has experienced an OutOfMemory error on Linux?

Long version:

I'm running some sort of application launcher. Basically it receives some input and reacts by spawning a slave Java application to process said input. This happens via a python script (to correctly handle  remote kill commands for it) which in turn calls a bash script (generated by Gradle and sets up the classpath) to actually spawn the slave.
The slave contains a worker thread and a monitor thread to make callbacks to a remote host for status updates. If status updates fail to occur for a set amount of time, the slave gets killed by the launcher. The reason for it not responding CAN be an OutOfMemoryError, however it can also be other reasons. I need to differentiate an OutOfMemoryError of the slave from some other error which caused it to stop working.
I don't just want to monitor memory usage and say once it reaches like 90% "ok that's enough". It may very well be that the GC succeeds in cleaning up sufficiently for the workload to finish. I only want to know if it failed to clean up and the JVM died because not enough memory could be freed.

What I have tried:

- Use the -XX:OnOutOfMemory flag as a JVM option for the slave which calls a script which in turn creates an empty flag file. I then check with the launcher for the existence of the flag file if the slave died. Worked like a charm on Windows, did not work at all on Unix because there is a funky bug which causes the execution of the flag call to require the exact same amount of Xmx the slave has used. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027434 for the bug. => Solution discarded because the slave needs the entire memory of the machine.
- `try{ longWork(); } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) { createOomFlagFile(); System.exit(100); }` This does work in some cases. However there are also cases where this does not happen and the monitor thread simply stops sending status updates. No exception occurs, no OOM flag file gets created. I know from SSHing onto the machine though that Java is eating all the memory available on the system and the whole system is slow.

Is there some (elegant) foolproof way to detect this which I am missing?

Comment: If in your second try no exception occurs why are you sure that the `longWork()` really failed because of not enough memory?

Comment: The thing is once no status update occurs for some time, the slave will get killed no matter what. And then it becomes necessary to know if it died to OutOfMemory or for some other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't wait for the OutOfMemory. My suggestion is, that you track memory consumption from the master application via Java Management Beans and issue warnings when memory consumption gets critical. I never did that on my own before, so I cannot get more precisely on how to do that, but maybe you find out or some others here can provide a solution.

**Edit:** this is the respective MXBean http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html

Comment: Here are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759831/how-do-i-access-memory-usage-programmatically-via-jmx

Comment: Just because the memory gets critically low it does not mean it will a) stay that way or b) that the GC will fail. So instead I really want to detect if the GC failed and memory consumption killed the JVM.

Comment: I now solved this by starting a watchdog thread in the slave which monitors memory consumption via `Runtime.getTotalMemory()` and `Runtime.getMaxMemory()`. The MXBean was not useful because it returned values which did not correspond to what Linux was telling me.Once a threshold is exceeded, a flag file is created. If the slave dies an unnatural death, the launcher checks for the existence of the flag file and acts on that.